# Why don't we use inheritance in react-native too often?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In react-native we generally do not extend all-ready built in objects, while in other programming languages such as swift, java, We often use inheritance. What are the drawback of using class inheritance  in react-native

```
export default class A extends Component 
{
}

export default class B extends A
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just extends your component to make a child component.

```
class Label extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.className='plain-label';
  }
   render(){
     return <span className={this.className}>
        {this.props.children} 
      </span>
   }
}


class SmallLabel extends Label{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.className = this.className + ' small-label';
  }
}
```

Then use it:

```
class Main extends React.Component{
    render(){
      ....
      <Label> Plain Label </Label>
      <SmallLabel> SmallLabel </SmallLabel>
    }
}
```

Inheritance is in most scenarios — just not good a viable solution. Because extending components with inheritance more or less lead to a scenario at some point, where the behaviors cannot be clubbed seamlessly. However, with Composition, it's possible.

Check this link: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html